# What is the best way to assign detection history using the following values?

Tags: r, matrix, detection, exponential

I have three years of detection data. In each year there are 8 probabilities at a site. These are no, a, n, na, l, la, ln, lna. I've assigned the values below:

```
no = 0
a = 1
n = 1
na = 2
l = 100
la = 101
ln = 101
lna = 102
```

In year 2, I wish to calculate and label all outcomes, so any combination of 2 of the terms above, to describe a detection history numerically.

So essentially I'm trying to get a list of 64 terms ranging from no,no to lna,lna with their respective values.

For example, no,no = 0 and lna,lna = 204

In year 3, I wish for the same. I'd like to calculate and label all possibilities. This needs to be arranged in two columns, one with history text, and one with history value.

```
x1         x2 
no,no,no   0
```

I'm sure this is possible, and possibly even basic. Though I have no idea where to begin.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are more elegant, concise ways to do it, but here's one approach:

1. Define the two lists of possibilities

```
poss = c("no", "a", "n", "na", "l", "la", "ln", "lna")
vals = c(1, 1, 2, 100, 101, 101, 101, 102)
```

2. Use `expand.grid` to enumerate the possibilities

```
output  <- expand.grid(poss, poss, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
comb_values <- expand.grid(vals, vals)
```

3. Write the ouput

```
output$names <- paste(output$Var1, output$Var2, sep = ",")
output$value <- comb_values$Var1 + comb_values$Var2
output$Var1 <- output$Var2 <- NULL
```

Result

```
     names value
1    no,no     2
2     a,no     2
3     n,no     3
4    na,no   101
5     l,no   102
6    la,no   102
7    ln,no   102
8   lna,no   103
9     no,a     2
10     a,a     2
11     n,a     3
12    na,a   101
13     l,a   102
14    la,a   102
15    ln,a   102
16   lna,a   103
17    no,n     3
18     a,n     3
19     n,n     4
20    na,n   102
21     l,n   103
22    la,n   103
23    ln,n   103
24   lna,n   104
25   no,na   101
26    a,na   101
27    n,na   102
28   na,na   200
29    l,na   201
30   la,na   201
31   ln,na   201
32  lna,na   202
33    no,l   102
34     a,l   102
35     n,l   103
36    na,l   201
37     l,l   202
38    la,l   202
39    ln,l   202
40   lna,l   203
41   no,la   102
42    a,la   102
43    n,la   103
44   na,la   201
45    l,la   202
46   la,la   202
47   ln,la   202
48  lna,la   203
49   no,ln   102
50    a,ln   102
51    n,ln   103
52   na,ln   201
53    l,ln   202
54   la,ln   202
55   ln,ln   202
56  lna,ln   203
57  no,lna   103
58   a,lna   103
59   n,lna   104
60  na,lna   202
61   l,lna   203
62  la,lna   203
63  ln,lna   203
64 lna,lna   204
```

Same logic for three days, just replace `poss, poss` with `poss, poss, poss` etc.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! I think this'll get me started just fine.